# How do I set retriever_method not in defaults?

Tags: ruby, dsl, mail-gem

Setting the `delivery_method` immediately within the `delivery` block instead of setting the `defaults` **to send** seems to work well with the following code:

```
    Mail.deliver do
      delivery_method :smtp,
        address: "smtp.gmail.com",
        domain: "#####",
        port: 587,
        user_name: from,
        password: "#####",
        enable_starttls_auto: true
      from     from
      to       to
      subject  subject
      body     "default body"
    end
```

But how do I do the same **to read**?

```
Mail.last do
  retriever_method :imap,
    user_name: to,
    password: password,
    address: server,
    port: port,
    enable_ssl: true
end
```

causes

```
*** NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `retriever_method' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Nested::Nested_2::Nested::Email_2:0x00007fa246110478>
```

Answer (score 1):

FYI: this gem is OSS.

`Mail#delivery_method` is technically an alias to [`Configuration.instance.delivery_method`](https://github.com/mikel/mail/blob/6bc16b4bce4fe280b19523c939b14a30e32a8ba4/lib/mail/mail.rb#L103-L105).

`Mail#retriever_method` in turn redirects to `Configuration.instance.retriever_method`.

Unlike `Mail::deliver`, that [creates a new instance](https://github.com/mikel/mail/blob/6bc16b4bce4fe280b19523c939b14a30e32a8ba4/lib/mail/mail.rb#L131-L135), `Mail::last` [explicitly calls `retriever_method.last(*args, &block)`](https://github.com/mikel/mail/blob/6bc16b4bce4fe280b19523c939b14a30e32a8ba4/lib/mail/mail.rb#L157-L159).

As one might see, [instance](https://github.com/mikel/mail/blob/6bc16b4bce4fe280b19523c939b14a30e32a8ba4/lib/mail/message.rb) allows to override `delivery_method`, but not `retriever_method`.

So you should store `Configuration.instance.retriever_method` into intermediate variable, update it, call `Mail::last` and restore it back. Somewhat along these lines:

```
Configuration.instance.instance_eval do
  generic_retriever_method = retriever_method
  retriever_method :imap,
    user_name: to,
    password: password,
    address: server,
    port: port,
    enable_ssl: true
  Mail.last
  retriever_method = generic_retriever_method
end
```

Comment: Oh, this is what I was afraid of ) thank you for investigation! Do you recommend another library?

Comment: I have no idea. I am not a big fan of using 3rd party hems, they always have glitches. BTW, what would be wrong with the workaround I proposed? You might dig in, or even fork and modify it to support multiple retrievers; it should not be complicated or time-consuming. Simply replicate functionality it has for deliveries—and voilà.